# How to Pass data into an SVG image file

Tags: angular, svg, ionic4

I am working on cleaning up code and all the icons that are on the application are raw svg images, that is to say that they are not referenced from an `<img src="path/here">"` and now I have ran into one that deals with the notifications and displaying the number of notifications from an Angular variable.

when the svg file is rawly entered into the Angular component the variable is correctly read, however, as one would correctly presume when the same code is in a `notification.svg`  file the words are presented literally

the part of the svg file that is worth showing is:

```
<text id="3-copy" font-family="Roboto-Black, Roboto" font-size="13" font-weight="700" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="6.73583984" y="15">{{notificationCount}}</tspan>
</text>
```

I know normally you can just pass by reference or you can pass with props. But, I think that creating a component JUST for this is overkill and a more simpler way without having 20+ lines of svg code in the application.

my question is this:

Is there a way to pass the value `5` to an svg file to be dynamically rendered *WITHOUT* having the svg code *IN* the application itself

Comment: So what is your question? What did you do? What is not working as expected?

Comment: sorry, updated question

Comment: The short answer is "no". The long one - you can read the file manually through http get request, parse it, modify and insert new DOM node, but I don't think this all worth it. Directives were created just for this.

Comment: Alright, thank you.